# Get Koa Actual route

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I am new in koa. I need to get a actual route in koa request.

Example 1 : If i hit a route  `/user` and i get the ctx origin url `/user/`.

Example 2 : If i hit a route `user/:id` and i get the ctx origin url `/user/1`.

I try to get the path like

```
exports.checkAuth = async ctx => {
   console.log(ctx.originalUrl); // return -> /user/1
   console.log(ctx.path); // return -> /user/1
 };
```

**I want to get the actual route path like `user/:id` in each request .**

In express route get a actual path like this

```
 app.get('/user/:id', function userIdHandler(req, res) {
     console.log(req.route);
 });
```

**Output:**

```
{ path: '/user/:id',
stack:
   [ { handle: [Function: userIdHandler],
   name: 'userIdHandler',
   params: undefined,
   path: undefined,
   keys: [],
   regexp: /^\/?$/i,
   method: 'get' } ],
methods: { get: true } }
```

Answer (score 3):

In koa.js when a route is matched, its path is available at `ctx._matchedRoute` and if named, the name is available at `ctx._matchedRouteName`

`ctx._matchedRoute` -> which will return in your case `user/:id`

Just keep in mind that ctx._matchedRoute is part of `koa-router`.